# How to extract particular field from my JSON string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have the following JSON string and I want to obtain `doc_count`:

```
import json

text = '''{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 11,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "range": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "2017-02-17T15:00:00.000Z-2017-02-17T16:00:00.000Z",
          "from": 1487343600000,
          "from_as_string": "2017-02-17T15:00:00.000Z",
          "to": 1487347200000,
          "to_as_string": "2017-02-17T16:00:00.000Z",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'''

obj = json.loads(text)

obj
```

I tried `obj['aggregations']['range']['buckets']['doc_count']`, but it does not work. How can I search through the hierarchy of this JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `'buckets'` key contains array of element. You needs

```
obj['aggregations']['range']['buckets'][0]['doc_count']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the fact that the `"buckets"` key contains a list.  You need:

```
obj['aggregations']['range']['buckets'][0]['doc_count']
```

Note the `[0]` after selecting the buckets key.